# Prime ideal of ring without gradation generating the prime homogeneous ideal contained in the same ring with gradation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings

Let $R=\oplus_{i\geq 0}R_i$ be a graded ring. Denote $S$ as the ring $R$ without gradation structure. Suppose $p\in Spec(S)$. I want to consider $Q=\oplus_ip\cap R_i$. Suppose $ab\in Q\subset p$ with $a,b$ homogeneous. Since $p$ is a prime ideal of $S$ and $ab\in p\subset S$, WLOG, I can assume $a\in p$. From $a$ homogeneous, $a\in R_i$ for some $i$. Hence, I see $Q$ is prime.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is above idea correct? It seems that every inhomogeneous ideal $p$ contains a "maximal" prime ideal $Q$ contained in it. I think the issue is $p\cap R_i$. This may need to generate a $R_0$ submodule of $R$ rather than naively taking intersection. If this is wrong, what is the counter example and what is the problem with above idea?

Comment: Take a look at Bruns and Herzog's amazing book ''Cohen Macaulay rings'', in Lemma 1.5.6. Actually, section 1.5 is a good source for details in the ''graded world''.

Comment: @ycidruiz Thanks. It is Lem. 1.5.6. I am right on this one.

Comment: Your $Q$ is in fact $p^*$ in the book notation.